# Mongo::Error::OperationFailure Unknown modifier: $pushAll when updating a model (mongoid, angular, rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-5, mongoid

I am using angular-8 on the front-end and Rails(5.2) on backend with Mongoid(6.1).

I have a multi-level nested form for model `Event` that accepts_nested_attributes_for `Ticket` that in turn accepts_nested_attributes_for `Channel`.

Whenever I try to update any event and add new `Channel` to any `Ticket` with in event. I receive this error:

> Mongo::Error::OperationFailure (Unknown modifier: $pushAll. Expected a valid update modifier or pipeline-style update specified as an array (9)):

I have looked it up and found [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5574), that $pushAll support is deprecated now and we have to [Turn on UsePushEach by default](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5670).

But I can't figure out **where should I configure this UsePushEach by default settings in Rails**.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you're referring to the Github issue of [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/) which is a node ODM and you're trying to apply their setup to Rails. They are quite different and their issues and solutions do not apply to each other.

In Mongoid, pushAll were removed since Mongoid 6.3 (see [MONGOID-4499](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MONGOID-4499)). You're seeing this error because you're using an old version of Mongoid.

Upgrading to the latest Mongoid (currently 7.0) should remove this error.

Comment: Updating my Mongoid gem from 6.1 to 6.3 fixed the Error for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

using $push you can use both single value and array of value

Both are valid

{"$push":{"column1":"value"}} // push individual value to column1 array type

{"$push":{"column1":[value]}} // append entire array to column1 array type(internally mongodb will use $each)